# Ignoring \n when reading from a file in C?

Tags: c, file

I was wondering if it is possible to ignore the new lines when reading a file. I've written a little program that reads the characters from a file and formats them but the new lines in the document mess up the formatting, I end up with double spaces where I only want a single spacing.

Is it possible to disable this feature? So that the only new lines my program prints out are the new lines that I insert into the print functions in my program?

Comment: Show your work so far and someone will be more likely to help you.

Comment: Certainly not with the standard input libraries. But it's quite easy to go through each read block of characters and remove the newlines. Why don't you do that?

Comment: @Gene Isn't getc in the standard input library?

Comment: Show your code that ends up with double spacing.  Show a sample input file (3 lines should be enough) and the desired output.  Depending on what you're after, you might read words with `scanf("%999s", buffer_1000)` which will blithely treat spaces, tabs and newlines as equivalent.  Please read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: When using `fgets` (the obvious choice) to read a file by line into `str`, you can remove the added `newline` with `str [ strcspn(str, "\r\n") ] = 0;` and that is harmless when there is no `newline` appended.

Comment: @WeatherVane That unnecessarily scans the whole string. You can instead just check the last two characters.

Comment: @Schwern if you mean the whole line, it only reads as much as the string buffer will hold.

Comment: @WeatherVane I mean it's an O(n) operation when it could be an O(1). Wait... nevermind... `strlen` is O(n) in C.

Comment: @nicomp Of course it is, but there's no way to tell the standard library to skip newlines. You read the newlines and then ignore them.

Comment: @Schwern thank you. Perhaps a sharper solution would read char by char.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's what `strcspn` already does. I'd go with an optimized standard library function than something home rolled.

Comment: @Schwern `strcspn` does not "read char by char", it scans a string already read. As you previously said, each string has to be scanned to use either `strlen` or `strcspn`. You are now contradicting yourself by saying "No don't read by char, scanning is more efficient".

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh, you meant reading the file character by character with `fgetc`. I thought you meant reading the string character by character with a while loop. Since file reads are block buffered, calling `fgetc` and looking for a newline might be a touch more efficient than `fgets` + `strlen` or `strcspn`. I might benchmark it.

Comment: @Schwern we are talking the same way at last!

Comment: @WeatherVane I coded them up and found fgets + strlen is fastest with fgets + strcpsn a very close second and fgetc trailing badly. Although I don't think my fgetc implementation is very good. I used /usr/share/dict/words and the text of the SQL 1992 standard for testing with output to /dev/null. [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/schwern/ae3250fdd2b21277c9987c65a49d13e7). We can talk about it [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c).

Comment: @Schwern that was an interesting comparison. Sorry I went offline in my time zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C doesn't provide much in the way of conveniences, you have to provide them all yourself or use a 3rd party library such as [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/). If you're new to C, get used to it. You're working very close to the bare <strike>metal</strike> silicon.

Generally you read a file line by line with [`fgets()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm), or my preference [POSIX getline()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), and strip the final newline off yourself by looking at the last index and replacing it with a null if it's a newline.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *line = NULL;
size_t line_capacity = 0; /* getline() will allocate line memory */

while( getline( &line, &line_capacity, fp ) > 0 ) {
    size_t last_idx = strlen(line) - 1;

    if( line[last_idx] == '\n' ) {
        line[last_idx] = '\0';
    }

    /* No double newline */
    puts(line);
}
```

You can put this into a little function for convenience. In many languages it's referred to as `chomp`.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool chomp( char *str ) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    /* Empty string */
    if( len == 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    size_t last_idx = len - 1;
    if( str[last_idx] == '\n' ) {
        srt[last_idx] = '\0';
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will be educational for you to implement `fgets` and `getline` yourself to understand how reading lines from a file actually works.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the detailed response. I will award you best answer, and close the thread. I found a way to do what I wanted. I used the following if anyone was wondering:  if (characters[i-1] != '\n') {printf("\n");}

Comment: I will take your advice, and I thank you for it. I only started writing code a couple of weeks back and I've only used C so far so I'm not very experienced.

Comment: @Gaarsin If you may take another piece of advice: start with a more modern language, particularly one that does memory management for you and has better string handling. Learning programming is hard enough: variables, loops, functions, indentation, objects, algorithmic thinking... without also having to worry about memory management every time you just want to concatenate two strings.

Comment: @Schwern Corner case: Consider what happens to `chomp()` if a line begins with a null character with `size_t last_idx = strlen(line) - 1;
    if( line[last_idx] == '\n' )`.  It leads to certain UB.  `line[strcspn(line, "\n") = 0;` is a nice alternative.

Comment: @chux Good point, I'll throw in a check and return. I'm not a fan of the `strcspn` version because it will eat the first newline, whereas `chomp` only eats a newline at the end.

Comment: @Schwern Note that a string returned from `fgets()` can only have, at most, 1 `'\n'`.  Still good and defensive  improvement to `chomp()`.  [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27729970/2410359)

Comment: @chux Right, it's intended as a general purpose string function.